# hamming distance python improvement

Tags: python, xor

I am trying to write hamming distance.
As input I do have two matrices M1 and M2, one is 40x20, second 50x20; they contain True/False. I need to calc distance between each row, so M1[0] distance with M2[0], M1[0] with M2[1] ... M1[39] with M2[49]. Resulting in 40x50 result matrix. My first try was of course looping like:

```
for x_i in range(X.shape[0]):
        for x_train_j in range(X_train.shape[0]):
            distance_results[x_i, x_train_j] = sum(np.logical_xor(x_array[x_i, :], x_train_array[x_train_j, :]))
```

it is correct, however, it is too slow for my data. I have some thoughts about multiplying `M1.dot(M2.T)`, which gives right shape of matrix and does summing in one step but when multiplying and summing xor is desired so:
`1 * 1 = 1` (need 0 - bad)
`1 * 0 = 0` (need 1 - bad)
`0 * 1 = 0` (need 1 - bad)
`0 * 0 = 0` (need 0 - is OK)
Do you have any idea how can I get desired result? I think i miss some math to do it right and fast.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try using numba to speed up execution. Numba provides "just in time" compiling to speed up execution. More info here: http://numba.pydata.org/
The given example (sum2d) can be easily adapted to fit your need.

Comment: my lecturer gave some advice on using scalar multiplication but i still cannot make it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M1.dot(M2.T)` could be in a way considered a `AND` for Boolean logic. For binary logic `A xor B` is equivalent to `(A and not B) or (not A and B)` so therefore one thing you could do --

```
M1.dot(M2.T):
1 * 1 = 1 
1 * 0 = 0 
0 * 1 = 0
0 * 0 = 0

(not M1).dot(M2.T):
0 * 1 = 0
0 * 0 = 0 
1 * 1 = 1
1 * 0 = 0

M1.dot(not M2.T):
1 * 0 = 0 
1 * 1 = 1
0 * 0 = 0
0 * 1 = 0

(not M1).dot(M2.T) or M1.dot(not M2.T):
0 * 1 || 1 * 0 = 0
0 * 0 || 1 * 1 = 1 
1 * 1 || 0 * 0 = 1
1 * 0 || 0 * 1 = 0
```

To code it up you need to be careful to cast out of logical before the dot so that the sum is calculated. If you dot on 2 logical arrays you wont get the result you want. I just use -1 as my not operator `( True - 1 = 0, False - 1 = -1)`. Also the 'or' here is really a sum since you are considering multiple bools. At the end you end up with your distances in the negative, easy to fix with absolute.

```
_A = [[ True,  True,  False],
      [ True,  False, True]]

_B = [[ True,  False, False],
      [ False, False, False],
      [ True,  True,  True ]]
```

Expected output:
    [[ 1, 2, 1],
     [ 1, 2, 1]]

```
A = numpy( _A, dtype=bool)
B = numpy( _B, dtype=bool)

numpy.absolute(numpy.dot(A,B.T-1) + numpy.dot(A-1, B.T))

>>>array([[1, 2, 1],
          [1, 2, 1]])
```

Comment: It does compute hamming distance. So I don't understand what it is missing

Comment: thanks man, gonna try it. Looks good. I was thinking about it but was missing how to make negative ( -1 trick). Dummy me ;;)